# CSS3 keyframes animation not rendering css file in IE10 only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, css-animations

Working on my new portfolio site for web design. First time I decided to jump into CSS3 animation keyframes. So far their really awesome and i can do some much with them, unless its IE10. Really can't figure it out, works great across all browsers, EXCEPT IE10. I know CSS3 keyframe animations are supported in IE10 but can't figure out why they are not loading in IE10 for some reason.

Here is the link to my new site I'm working on. http://www.rauftur.com/2013

The CSS file with all the keyframes animations is located in styles/animation.css. When I open up that file in the developer toolbar in IE10 it comes up empty. Not sure whats causing the conflict, been scratching my head for a few days on this one. Maybe a new set of eyes looking at it might be able to point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You missed to close some `)` in your transform values.

Comment: Wow, i was reading way too deep into it. Thanks for noticing! Can't believe it was something as simple has forgetting to close the statement.